# Making .next() compatible with both python 2 and 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, iterator

I have written code in python 2.7 that I  want to make it compatible with
 Python 3.x. So far I have tried the `futurize` and `modernize` python packages as well as `2to3`, and everything seems fine.

But I'm stuck with python 2.7's `.next()` method. And I get warning with both the `futurize` and `2to3` packages, like:

```
RefactoringTool: Line 34: Calls to builtin next() possibly shadowed by global binding
```

And when I run actual code in python 3.x it gives me this warning:

```
AttributeError: 'itertools._grouper' object has no attribute 'next'
```

The relevant code in python 2.7 is as follows:

```
with open('file.txt', 'rU') as f:
    l = f.readlines()[2:]
    up = (x[1] for x in groupby(l, lambda line: line[0] == ">"))
    for u in up:
        head = u.next()[1:].strip()
        q = "".join(s.strip() for s in u.next())
        # do something
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't call the `.next()` method directly. Use the [`next()` *function*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) on an iterator instead:

```
for u in up:
    head = next(u)[1:].strip()
    q = "".join(s.strip() for s in next(u))
```

The `next()` function will invoke the correct hook on both Python 2 and 3.

However, the error message you see from `futurize` indicates that you may *also* have bound the name `next` elsewhere in your code.

If you have something like:

```
next = some_expression
```

or

```
def next(...):
    # some function
```

as a global, then you are *shadowing* the built-in `next()` function. Rename any other use of `next` as a global in that module to avoid issues.

For example, the following demo code throws the message you see:

```
$ cat demo.py
def next(): pass
n = g.next()
$ bin/futurize demo.py
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: idioms
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
RefactoringTool: Refactored demo.py
--- demo.py (original)
+++ demo.py (refactored)
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
 def next(): pass
-n = g.next()
+n = g.__next__()
RefactoringTool: Files that need to be modified:
RefactoringTool: demo.py
RefactoringTool: Warnings/messages while refactoring:
RefactoringTool: ### In file demo.py ###
RefactoringTool: Line 1: Calls to builtin next() possibly shadowed by global binding
RefactoringTool: ### In file demo.py ###
RefactoringTool: Line 1: Calls to builtin next() possibly shadowed by global binding
```

Note how the tool then used `g.__next__()` instead of `g.next()`, to avoid using `next()` as a function.

Removing the `next` function from that code results in:

```
$ cat demo.py
# def next(): pass
n = g.next()
$ bin/futurize demo.py
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: idioms
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
RefactoringTool: Refactored demo.py
--- demo.py (original)
+++ demo.py (refactored)
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
 # def next(): pass
-n = g.next()
+n = next(g)
RefactoringTool: Files that need to be modified:
RefactoringTool: demo.py
```